# AWS instance access: two corporate computers, only one can access

Tags: amazon-web-services

Driving me crazy for hours now: as of yesterday, my corporate laptop can access an AWS instance, but using the same exact credentials / ports my desktop cannot.  Both on the same network.  I'm on a Windows environment, just installed Amazon's cli, and have been trying to figure out what diagnostic statements to issue either to the windows command line or to the aws cli.  Anyone have any ideas that might help?  Thank you!

Comment: check the security groups. if you set it up on one of the computers, it might have defaulted to only allowing that ip address.

Comment: What do you mean by "Access"? have you ensured the associated key files have been copied to the desktop machine if attempting to execute CLI based commands?

Comment: actually before this morning, there was no amazon cli.  I was simply connecting to the instance using psycopg via python.  As of yesterday, that same exact call only works on my laptop and not my desktop.  Maybe something changed on the Amazon side, but I sort of doubt it.

Comment: If exactly the same thing works from your laptop but not your desktop and they are both on the same network, then the problem clearly lies with the configuration on the desktop. This type of question is out-of-scope for StackOverflow, which is focussed on programming questions.

Comment: @user3161791 As marcello suggested, I would suggest you to look at the security group of that EC2 instance. It may be that the access to specific IPs is only allowed, and your laptop is one of that.